# How can you create bold text from a formula in microsoft excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Im concatenating a number of text fields and want to make one of the filed bold in the final out put how can this be done?

Comment: `Copy` `PasteValues`, then select the characters you wish to bold format (in the formula bar) and select **Bold**.  Done easiest using VBA.

Answer (score 5):

> want to make one of the filed bold in the final out put how can this be done?

There is no way for that, you can't have character level formatting in cells which contain a formula.

Your two workarounds:

- have the same formatting for all text in the cell
- convert formula output to constant before formatting

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants Adrian's formula with lowercase included, and doesn't feel like spending 5 minutes on it like I did:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z","")
```

Unfortunately I could not find any bold punctuation characters.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, finally a problem for which `SWITCH` was actually made! Not the cheesy examples help sites give!

```
=SWITCH(UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),
               65,"",66,"",67,"",68,"",69,"",70,"",71,"",72,"",73,"",74,"",75,"",76,"",77,"",78,"",79,"",80,"",81,"",82,"",83,"",84,"",85,"",86,"",87,"",88,"",89,"",90,"",
               97,"",98,"",99,"",100,"",101,"",102,"",103,"",104,"",105,"",106,"",107,"",108,"",109,"",110,"",111,"",112,"",113,"",114,"",115,"",116,"",117,"",118,"",119,"",120,"",121,"",122,"",
               48,"",49,"",50,"",51,"",52,"",53,"",54,"",55,"",56,"",57,""
               )
```

The big reason to use `SWITCH` in this problem is calculation time since there is only one function to compute on each input, not 62. Not a problem if a one-off, but 10,000 rows means 620,000 calculations on it, not 10,000 so get to 30-40-100-200,000 rows and you could have a real problem.

Also, copied and pasted into the Formula Editor, it lays out nicely for readability. (Those rows line up under the "U" in "UNICODE", not way to the right as here.)

This version preserves case in the exchange as well as being simple to build the list of values, string-wise. (**NOT** simple to build as in the work `Adrian Mihai Nemes` went through to find these characters!)

The `SUBSTITUTE` approaches preserve case nicely, as a matter of course. Using `SWITCH` directly on the `MID`, like in these, will not because it does not seem to be case sensitive. Hence the conversion through `UNICODE` to Unicode values for the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem, but I found a solution. This solution works well in google sheets.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9","")
```

This solution works just for numbers and capital letters. If you want to improve your formula, use the characters below:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```